# Send selected token (the one you deployed) with web3js

Tags: web3js, transactions, tokens, contract-deployment

How to send a transaction of a token that I have in my wallet other than the default one like ether in Ethereum without a contract method just with web3js?

Answer (score 0):

To interact with a contract on a blockchain, you must have to communicate with a `RPC` or any other endpoint prefer. To that you may have to use a direct API call, a library like `web3` or `ethers` from a script, a web interface like a blockscan website (etherscan, bscscan, etc...) provide or a wallet application.

**However you have to call the contract method `transfer` or `transferFrom` directly or indirectly**.